# How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I'm using `$.post()` to call a servlet using Ajax and then using the resulting HTML fragment to replace a `div` element in the user's current page. However, if the session times out, the server sends a redirect directive to send the user to the login page. In this case, jQuery is replacing the `div` element with the contents of the login page, forcing the user's eyes to witness a rare scene indeed.

How can I manage a redirect directive from an Ajax call with jQuery 1.2.6?

Comment: (not an answer as such) - I've done this in the past by editing the jquery library and adding a check for the login page on each XHR complete. Not the best solution because it would have to be done each time you upgrade, but it does solve the problem.

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941933/update-whole-page-on-ajax-request

Comment: The `HttpContext.Response.AddHeader` and check at ajaxsetup sucess is the way to go

Comment: Why cant the server return 401? In that case you can have a global  $.ajaxSetup and use the status code to redirect the page.

Comment: this link http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/spring-security-part-vi-session-timeout-handling-for-ajax-calls/ gives me the right solution

Comment: Plese have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The solution that was eventually implemented was to use a wrapper for the callback function of the Ajax call and in this wrapper check for the existence of a specific element on the returned HTML chunk. If the element was found then the wrapper executed a redirection. If not, the wrapper forwarded the call to the actual callback function.

For example, our wrapper function was something like:

```
function cbWrapper(data, funct){
    if($("#myForm", data).length > 0)
        top.location.href="login.htm";//redirection
    else
        funct(data);
}
```

Then, when making the Ajax call we used something like:

```
$.post("myAjaxHandler", 
       {
        param1: foo,
        param2: bar
       },
       function(data){
           cbWrapper(data, myActualCB);
       }, 
       "html"
);
```

This worked for us because all Ajax calls always returned HTML inside a DIV element that we use to replace a piece of the page. Also, we only needed to redirect to the login page.

Comment: Note that this can be shortened to function cbWrapper(funct) { return function(data) { if($("#myForm", data).size() > 0) top.location.href="login"; else funct(data); } } . You then only need cbWrapper(myActualCB) when calling .post. Yes, code in comments is a mess but it should be noted :)

Comment: size is depreciated so you can use .length here in place of size

Answer (score 764):

I read this question and implemented the approach that has been stated regarding setting the response *HTTP status code* to 278 in order to avoid the browser transparently handling the redirects. Even though this worked, I was a little dissatisfied as it is a bit of a hack.

After more digging around, I ditched this approach and used [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). In this case, all responses to AJAX requests have the *status code* 200 and the body of the response contains a JSON object that is constructed on the server. The JavaScript on the client can then use the JSON object to decide what it needs to do.

I had a similar problem to yours. I perform an AJAX request that has 2 possible responses: one that *redirects* the browser to a new page and one that *replaces* an existing HTML form on the current page with a new one. The jQuery code to do this looks something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: reqUrl,
    data: reqBody,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        if (data.redirect) {
            // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        } else {
            // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
            $("#myform").replaceWith(data.form);
        }
    }
});
```

The JSON object "data" is constructed on the server to have 2 members: `data.redirect` and `data.form`. I found this approach to be much better.

Comment: As stated in the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery it is better to use window.location.replace(data.redirect); than window.location.href = data.redirect;

Answer (score 268):

I solved this issue by:

1. Adding a custom header to the response:

   ```
   public ActionResult Index(){
       if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
       {
           HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("REQUIRES_AUTH","1");
       }
       return View();
   }
   ```
2. Binding a JavaScript function to the [`ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) event and checking to see if the header exists:

   ```
   $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, request, settings) {
       if (request.getResponseHeader('REQUIRES_AUTH') === '1') {
          window.location = '/';
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: What an awesome solution. I like the idea of a one-stop solution. I need to check for a 403 status, but I can use the ajaxSuccess bind on body for this (which is what I was really looking for.) Thanks.

Comment: I just did this and found that I needed ajaxComplete where I was using the $.get() function and any status other than 200 was not firing. In fact, I could have probably just bound to ajaxError instead. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: This worked great for me.  Just set the javascript to reload the current page with `location.reload();` as our model requires redirect to a separate authorization site.

Comment: It's ok in many cases, but what if your framework handles authorization ?

Comment: This solution requires the browser to know the URL for authentication.  Although this solves the problem, it is (in my opinion) not a maintainable solution.  If the authentication controller changes, now you are maintaining the routes file and the javascript.  i.e. This is bad programming practice.

Comment: I like the header approach but also think - like @mwoods79 - that the knowledge of where to redirect to should not be duplicated. I solved that by adding a header REDIRECT_LOCATION instead of a boolean.

Comment: Take care to set the header on the response AFTER the redirect. As described in other answers on this page, the redirect may be transparent to the ajaxSucces handler. Thus I included the header on the GET response of the login page (which was eventually and only triggering ajaxSuccess in my scenario).

Comment: And you could add this check somewhere in `Global.asax`. In `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this on Spring Security?

Answer (score 126):

No browsers handle 301 and 302 responses correctly. And in fact the standard even says they should handle them "transparently" which is a MASSIVE headache for Ajax Library vendors. In [Ra-Ajax](http://code.google.com/p/ra-ajax/) we were forced into using HTTP response status code 278 (just some "unused" success code) to handle transparently redirects from the server...

This really annoys me, and if someone here have some "pull" in W3C I would appreciate that you could let W3C *know* that we really need to handle 301 and 302 codes ourselves...! ;)

Comment: I for one move that 278 should become apart of the official HTTP Spec.

Comment: Doesn't it already handle them transparently? If a resource has moved, handling it transparently means repeating the request on the provided URL. That is what I would expect using the XMLHttpRequest API.

Comment: @PhilippeRathé Agree. Transparently handling is just what I want. And I don't know why it is considered bad.

Comment: @smwikipedia To arrange for a redirect of the markup in main section without redirecting the page.

Comment: if someone here have some "pull" in W3C I would appreciate that you could let W3C know that we really need to handle 301 and 302 codes ourselves...! ;)

Comment: Browsers handle it transparently since day one. What is an ajax request? It's when you want a browser to do a request and return the result. What *you* want is a special case: "...return the result, but in case of a redirect don't return the result." That might annoy you as a library developer, because you're trying to handle the general case, change the way browsers work. But since you do, you should expect annoyances.

Comment: ...In general case that's an issue, but when is it needed? The OP is the only case I now know, which is covered by a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call?page=1&tab=votes#comment30937775_199099).

Comment: See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call?page=1&tab=votes#comment117733606_1534662).

Comment: I think status code 201 should be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 76):

I like Timmerz's method with a slight twist of lemon. If you ever get returned **contentType** of **text/html** when you're expecting **JSON**, you are most likely being redirected. In my case, I just simply reload the page, and it gets redirected to the login page. Oh, and check that the jqXHR status is 200, which seems silly, because you are in the error function, right? Otherwise, legitimate error cases will force an iterative reload (oops)

```
$.ajax(
   error:  function (jqXHR, timeout, message) {
    var contentType = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
    if (jqXHR.status === 200 && contentType.toLowerCase().indexOf("text/html") >= 0) {
        // assume that our login has expired - reload our current page
        window.location.reload();
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks a lot Brian, your answer was the best for my scenario, although I would like if there was a safer check such as comparing which url/page is redirecting to instead of the simple "content-type" check. I was unable to find which page is redirecting to from the jqXHR object.

Comment: I checked for status 401 and then redirect. Works like a champ.

Answer (score 59):

Use the low-level `$.ajax()` call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/yourservlet",
  data: { },
  complete: function(xmlHttp) {
    // xmlHttp is a XMLHttpRquest object
    alert(xmlHttp.status);
  }
});
```

Try this for a redirect:

```
if (xmlHttp.code != 200) {
  top.location.href = '/some/other/page';
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the low level stuff. Anyway, suppose I use something like what you describe, how do I force a browser redirection once I detect that the HTTP code is 3xx? My goal is to redirect the user, not just to announce that his/her session has expired.

Comment: Btw, $.ajax() is not very, very low-level. It's just low-level in terms of jQuery because there is $.get, $.post, etc. which are much more simple than $.ajax and all its options.

Comment: Yeah, I now using JQuery is not really low-level, I was being dramatic! BTW, your answer was really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Oh boy! Sorry I had to "un-accept" your answer, it still very helpful. Thing is, redirections are automatically managed by the XMLHttpRequest, hence I ALWAYS get a 200 status code after the redirection (sigh!). I think I will have to do something nasty like parsing the HTML and look for a marker.

Comment: I corrected the code. Thanks. Sorry that I couldn't be of more help. By the way, this is one of the reasons why people implement a response format (e.g. XML or JSON) which contains a more verbose status etc.. Look into that maybe. Or let me know, I can post an example if you need.

Comment: Just curious, if the session ends at the server, doesn't that mean the server sends a different SESSIONID? couldn't we just detect that?

Comment: NOTE: This does not work for redirects. ajax will go to the new page and return its status code.

Comment: You always get 200 response code in case of a 302 response from the server. The browser transparently handles that 302 and makes a second request to the new location.

Answer (score 36):

I just wanted to share my approach as this might it might help someone:

I basically included a JavaScript module which handles the authentication stuff like displaying the username and also this case handling the **redirect to the login page**.

My scenario: We basically have an ISA server in between which listens to all requests and **responds with a 302 and a location header** to our login page.

In my JavaScript module my **initial approach** was something like

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){
    if(xhr.status === 302){
        //check for location header and redirect...
    }
});
```

The problem (as many here already mentioned) is that the browser handles the redirect by itself wherefore my `ajaxComplete` callback got never called, but instead I got the **response of the already redirected Login page** which obviously was a `status 200`. The problem: how do you detect whether the successful 200 response is your actual login page or just some other arbitrary page??

### The solution

Since I was not able to capture 302 redirect responses, I added a `LoginPage` header on my login page which contained the url of the login page itself. In the module I now listen for the header and do a redirect:

```
if(xhr.status === 200){
    var loginPageRedirectHeader = xhr.getResponseHeader("LoginPage");
    if(loginPageRedirectHeader && loginPageRedirectHeader !== ""){
        window.location.replace(loginPageRedirectHeader);
    }
}
```

...and that works like charm :). You might wonder why I include the url in the `LoginPage` header...well basically because I found no way of determining the url of `GET` resulting from the automatic location redirect from the `xhr` object...

Comment: +1 - but custom headers are supposed to start with `X-`, so a better header to use would be `X-LoginPage: http://example.com/login`.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff Not any more. I didn't use the X- prefix because in [June 2011](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-saintandre-xdash-00) an ITEF document proposed their deprecation and indeed, with [June 2012](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6648.txt) it is no official that custom headers should no more be prefixed with `X-`.

Comment: We also have an ISA server and I just ran into the same issue.  Rather than work around it in code, we used the instructions in [kb2596444](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2596444) to configure ISA to stop redirecting.

Answer (score 31):

I know this topic is old, but I'll give yet another approach I've found and previously described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049690/session-cookies-expiration-handling-in-asp-net-mvc-3-while-using-wif-and-jquery). Basically I'm using ASP.MVC with WIF *(but this is not really important for the context of this topic - answer is adequate no matter which frameworks are used. The clue stays unchanged - dealing with issues related to authentication failures while performing ajax requests)*.

The approach shown below can be applied to all ajax requests out of the box (if they do not redefine beforeSend event obviously).

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: checkPulse,
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        document.open();
        document.write(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        document.close();
    }
});
```

Before any ajax request is performed `CheckPulse` method is invoked (the controller method which can be anything simplest):

```
[Authorize]
public virtual void CheckPulse() {}
```

If user is not authenticated (token has expired) such method cannot be accessed (protected by `Authorize` attribute). Because the framework handles authentication, while token expires, it puts http status 302 to the response. If you don't want your browser to handle 302 response transparently, catch it in Global.asax and change response status - for example to 200 OK. Additionally, add header, which instructs you to process such response in special way (later at the client side):

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 302
        && (new HttpContextWrapper(Context)).Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {                
        Context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        Context.Response.AddHeader("REQUIRES_AUTH", "1");
    }
}
```

Finally at the client side check for such custom header. If present - full redirection to logon page should be done (in my case `window.location` is replaced by url from request which is handled automatically by my framework).

```
function checkPulse(XMLHttpRequest) {
    var location = window.location.href;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Controller/CheckPulse",
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        beforeSend: null,
        success:
            function (result, textStatus, xhr) {
                if (xhr.getResponseHeader('REQUIRES_AUTH') === '1') {
                    XMLHttpRequest.abort(); // terminate further ajax execution
                    window.location = location;
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: I fixed the problem by using the PostAuthenticateRequest event instead of the EndRequest event.

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko I pasted the wrong event into my last reply! I meant the PreSendRequestHeaders event.....not PostAuthenticateRequest! >>blush<< thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko when using WIF you can also return 401 responses for AJAX requests and let your javascript handle these. Also you're assuming that all 302 require authentication which might not be true in all cases. I've added an answer if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 30):

I think a better way to handle this is to leverage the existing HTTP protocol response codes, specifically `401 Unauthorized`.

Here is how I solved it:

1. Server side: If session expires, and request is ajax. send a 401 response code header
2. Client side: Bind to the ajax events

   ```
   $('body').bind('ajaxSuccess',function(event,request,settings){
   if (401 == request.status){
       window.location = '/users/login';
   }
   }).bind('ajaxError',function(event,request,settings){
   if (401 == request.status){
       window.location = '/users/login';
   }
   });
   ```

IMO this is more generic and you are not writing some new custom spec/header.  You also should not have to modify any of your existing ajax calls.

**Edit:** Per @Rob's comment below, 401 (the HTTP status code for authentication errors) should be the indicator. See [403 Forbidden vs 401 Unauthorized HTTP responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses) for more detail. With that being said some web frameworks use 403 for both authentication AND authorization errors - so adapt accordingly. Thanks Rob.

Comment: I use the same approach. Does jQuery really calls ajaxSuccess on 403 error code? I think only ajaxError part is actually needed

Answer (score 25):

I resolved this issue like this:

Add a middleware to process response, if it is a redirect for an ajax request, change the response to a normal response with the redirect url.

```
class AjaxRedirect(object):
  def process_response(self, request, response):
    if request.is_ajax():
      if type(response) == HttpResponseRedirect:
        r = HttpResponse(json.dumps({'redirect': response['Location']}))
        return r
    return response
```

Then in ajaxComplete, if the response contains redirect, it must be a redirect, so change the browser's location.

```
$('body').ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, settings) {
   if (xhr.status == 200) {
       var redirect = null;
       try {
           redirect = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).redirect;
           if (redirect) {
               window.location.href = redirect.replace(/\?.*$/, "?next=" + window.location.pathname);
           }
       } catch (e) {
           return;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Another solution I found (especially useful if you want to set a global behaviour) is to use the [`$.ajaxsetup()` method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) together with the [`statusCode` property](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/). Like others pointed out, don't use a redirect statuscode (`3xx`), instead use a `4xx` statuscode and handle the redirect client-side.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
  statusCode : {
    400 : function () {
      window.location = "/";
    }
  }
});
```

Replace `400` with the statuscode you want to handle. Like already mentioned `401 Unauthorized` could be a good idea. I use the `400` since it's very unspecific and I can use the `401` for more specific cases (like wrong login credentials). So instead of redirecting directly your backend should return a `4xx` error-code when the session timed out and you you handle the redirect client-side. Works perfect for me even with frameworks like backbone.js

Comment: Where to mention the function on page?

Comment: @Vikrant If I understand your question correctly, you can call the function right after jQuery is loaded and before you're doing your actual requests.

Answer (score 20):

I have a simple solution that works for me, no server code change needed...just add a tsp of nutmeg...

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(document).ajaxSend(
    function(event,request,settings)
    {
        var intercepted_success = settings.success;
        settings.success = function( a, b, c ) 
        {  
            if( request.responseText.indexOf( "<html>" ) > -1 )
                window.location = window.location;
            else
                intercepted_success( a, b, c );
        };
    });
});
```

I check the presence of html tag, but you can change the indexOf to search for whatever unique string exists in your login page...

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, it keeps on calling the function defined with ajax call, it's like it is not overriding the success method.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, at least anymore. Possible explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12010724/260665

Answer (score 20):

Most of the given solutions use a workaround, using an extra header or an inappropiate HTTP code. Those solutions will most probably work but feel a bit 'hacky'. I've come up with another solution.

We're using WIF which is configured to redirect (passiveRedirectEnabled="true") on a 401 response. The redirect is usefull when handling normal requests but won't work for AJAX requests (since browsers won't execute the 302/redirect).

Using the following code in your global.asax you can disable the redirect for AJAX requests:

```
    void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_AuthorizationFailed(object sender, AuthorizationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        string requestedWithHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedWithHeader) && requestedWithHeader.Equals("XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            e.RedirectToIdentityProvider = false;
        }
    }
```

This allows you to return 401 responses for AJAX requests, which your javascript can then handle by reloading the page. Reloading the page  will throw a 401 which will be handled by WIF (and WIF will redirect the user to the login page).

An example javascript to handle 401 errors:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {

    if (jqxhr.status == 401) { //Forbidden, go to login
        //Use a reload, WIF will redirect to Login
        location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Good solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

This problem may appear then using ASP.NET MVC RedirectToAction method. To prevent form displaying the response in div you can simply do some kind of ajax response filter for incomming responses with **$.ajaxSetup**. If the response contains MVC redirection you can evaluate this expression on JS side. Example code for JS below:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataFilter: function (data, type) {
        if (data && typeof data == "string") {
            if (data.indexOf('window.location') > -1) {
                eval(data);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```

If data is: *"window.location = '/Acount/Login'"* above filter will catch that and evaluate to make the redirection instead of letting the data to be displayed.

Comment: `data` is in the response body or header?

Answer (score 17):

Putting together what Vladimir Prudnikov and Thomas Hansen said:

- Change your server-side code to detect if it's an XHR. If it is, set the response code of the redirect to 278.
  In django:

> ```
>    if request.is_ajax():
>       response.status_code = 278
> ```

This makes the browser treat the response as a success, and hand it to your Javascript.

- In your JS, make sure the form submission is via Ajax, check the response code and redirect if needed:

> ```
> $('#my-form').submit(function(event){ 
>
>   event.preventDefault();   
>   var options = {
>     url: $(this).attr('action'),
>     type: 'POST',
>     complete: function(response, textStatus) {    
>       if (response.status == 278) { 
>         window.location = response.getResponseHeader('Location')
>       }
>       else { ... your code here ... } 
>     },
>     data: $(this).serialize(),   
>   };   
>   $.ajax(options); 
> });
> ```

Answer (score 13):

```
    <script>
    function showValues() {
        var str = $("form").serialize();
        $.post('loginUser.html', 
        str,
        function(responseText, responseStatus, responseXML){
            if(responseStatus=="success"){
                window.location= "adminIndex.html";
            }
        });     
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 13):

Let me just quote again the problem as described by @Steg

> I had a similar problem to yours. I perform an ajax request that has 2
>   possible responses: one that redirects the browser to a new page and
>   one that replaces an existing HTML form on the current page with a new
>   one.

IMHO this is a real challenge and will have to be officially extended to the current HTTP standards.

I believe the new Http Standard will be to use a new status-code.
meaning: currently `301/302` tells the browser to go and fetch the content of *this* request to a new `location`.

In the extended standard, it will say that if the response `status: 308` (just an example), then the browser should redirect the main page to the `location` provided.

That being said; I'm inclined to already mimic this *future* behavior, and therefore when a document.redirect is needed, I have the server respond as:

```
status: 204 No Content
x-status: 308 Document Redirect
x-location: /login.html
```

When JS gets the "`status: 204`", it checks for the existence of the `x-status: 308` header, and does a document.redirect to the page provided in the `location` header.

Does this make any sense to you?

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#site").length > 0) {
            window.location = "<%= Url.Content("~") %>" + "Login/LogOn";
        }
    });
```

Put it on the login page. If it was loaded in a div on the main page, it will redirect til the login page. "#site" is a id of a div which is located on all pages except login page.

Answer (score 12):

While the answers seem to work for people if you're using Spring Security I have found extending LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint and adding specific code to handle AJAX more robust.  Most of the examples intercept *all* redirects not just authentication failures.  This was undesirable for the project I work on.  You may find the need to also extend ExceptionTranslationFilter and override the "sendStartAuthentication" method to remove the caching step if you don't want the failed AJAX request cached.

Example AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
public class AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint extends
    LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    public AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint(String loginUrl) {
        super(loginUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (isAjax(request)) {
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Please re-authenticate yourself");
        } else {
        super.commence(request, response, authException);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isAjax(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request != null && "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
    }
}
```

Sources:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242174/handle-session-expired-event-in-spring-based-web-application), [2](http://yoyar.com/blog/2012/06/dealing-with-the-spring-security-ajax-session-timeout-problem/)

Comment: It would be helpful (to me) if down voters would explain why they are down voting.  If there is something bad with this solution I would like to learn from my mistakes.  Thanks.

Comment: If using Spring and also using JSF, then also check for this: ("partial/ajax").equalsIgnoreCase(request.getHeader("faces-request"));

Comment: Users might have voted down because you didn't mention: (1) the requisite client-side mods to detect your error response; (2) the requisite mods to Spring configuration to add your customized LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint to the filter chain.

Comment: Your answer is similar to this one from @Arpad. It worked for me; using Spring Security 3.2.9. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426947/4505142

Answer (score 11):

I solved this by putting the following in my login.php page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location.href.indexOf('login.php') == -1) {
        top.location.href = '/login.php';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Some might find the below useful:

I wanted clients to be redirected to the login page for any rest-action that is sent without an authorization token. Since all of my rest-actions are Ajax based, I needed a good generic way to redirect to the login page instead of handling the Ajax success function.

This is what I've done:

On any Ajax request my server will return a Json 200 response "NEED TO AUTHENTICATE" (if the client needs to authenticate).

Simple example in Java (server side):

```
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger m_logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);

    public static final String COOKIE_NAME = "token_cookie"; 

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {        
        // Check if it has a cookie.
        try {
            Map<String, Cookie> cookies = context.getCookies();

            if (!cookies.containsKey(COOKIE_NAME)) {
                m_logger.debug("No cookie set - redirect to login page");
                throw new AuthenticationException();
            }
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            context.abortWith(Response.ok("\"NEED TO AUTHENTICATE\"").type("json/application").build());
        }
    }
}
```

In my Javascript I've added the following code:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    var originalSuccess = options.success;

    options.success = function(data) {
        if (data == "NEED TO AUTHENTICATE") {
            window.location.replace("/login.html");
        }
        else {
            originalSuccess(data);
        }
    };      
});
```

And that's about it.

Answer (score 5):

in the servlet you should put 
`response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);`
to send the '301' xmlHttp status you need for a redirection...

and in the $.ajax function you should not use the `.toString()` function..., just

`if (xmlHttp.status == 301) {
    top.location.href = 'xxxx.jsp';
}`

the problem is it is not very flexible, you can't decide where you want to redirect..

redirecting through the servlets should be the best way. but i still can not find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to latch on to any ajax requests for the entire page. @SuperG got me started. Here is what I ended up with:

```
// redirect ajax requests that are redirected, not found (404), or forbidden (403.)
$('body').bind('ajaxComplete', function(event,request,settings){
        switch(request.status) {
            case 301: case 404: case 403:                    
                window.location.replace("http://mysite.tld/login");
                break;
        }
});
```

I wanted to specifically check for certain http status codes to base my decision on. However, you can just bind to ajaxError to get anything other than success (200 only perhaps?) I could have just written:

```
$('body').bind('ajaxError', function(event,request,settings){
    window.location.replace("http://mysite.tld/login");
}
```

Comment: the latter would hide any other errors making troubleshooting problematic

Comment: A 403 does not mean that the user isn't authenticated, it means that the (probably authenticated) user does not have permission to view the requested resource. So it should not redirect to the login page

Answer (score 5):

If you also want to pass the values then you can also set the session variables and access 
Eg: 
In your jsp you can write

```
<% HttpSession ses = request.getSession(true);
   String temp=request.getAttribute("what_you_defined"); %>
```

And then you can store this temp value in your javascript variable and play around

Answer (score 5):

I didn't have any success with the header solution - they were never picked up in my ajaxSuccess / ajaxComplete method. I used Steg's answer with the custom response, but I modified the JS side some. I setup a method that I call in each function so I can use standard `$.get` and `$.post` methods.

```
function handleAjaxResponse(data, callback) {
    //Try to convert and parse object
    try {
        if (jQuery.type(data) === "string") {
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        }
        if (data.error) {
            if (data.error == 'login') {
                window.location.reload();
                return;
            }
            else if (data.error.length > 0) {
                alert(data.error);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(ex) { }

    if (callback) {
        callback(data);
    }
}
```

Example of it in use...

```
function submitAjaxForm(form, url, action) {
    //Lock form
    form.find('.ajax-submit').hide();
    form.find('.loader').show();

    $.post(url, form.serialize(), function (d) {
        //Unlock form
        form.find('.ajax-submit').show();
        form.find('.loader').hide();

        handleAjaxResponse(d, function (data) {
            // ... more code for if auth passes ...
        });
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I solve the problem by adding a custom `HTTP Header`. Just before response for every request in server side, i add the current requested url to response's header.

My application type on server is `Asp.Net MVC`, and it has a good place to do it. in `Global.asax` i implemented the `Application_EndRequest` event so:

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

    //  ...
    //  ...

        protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
            app.Context.Response.Headers.Add("CurrentUrl",app.Context. Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath);
        }

    }
```

It works perfect for me! Now in every response of the `JQuery` `$.post` i have the requested `url` and also other response headers which comes as result of `POST` method by status `302`, `303` ,... .

and other important thing is that there is no need to modify code on server side nor client side.

and the next is the ability to get access to the other information of post action such errors, messages, and ..., In this way.

I posted this, maybe help someone :)

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem on a django app I'm tinkering with (disclaimer: I'm tinkering to learn, and am in no way an expert). What I wanted to do was use jQuery ajax to send a DELETE request to a resource, delete it on the server side, then send a redirect back to (basically) the homepage. When I sent `HttpResponseRedirect('/the-redirect/')` from the python script, jQuery's ajax method was receiving 200 instead of 302. So, what I did was to send a response of 300 with:

```
response = HttpResponse(status='300')
response['Location'] = '/the-redirect/' 
return  response
```

Then I sent/handled the request on the client with jQuery.ajax like so:

```
<button onclick="*the-jquery*">Delete</button>

where *the-jquery* =
$.ajax({ 
  type: 'DELETE', 
  url: '/resource-url/', 
  complete: function(jqxhr){ 
    window.location = jqxhr.getResponseHeader('Location'); 
  } 
});
```

Maybe using 300 isn't "right", but at least it worked just like I wanted it to.

PS :this was a huge pain to edit on the mobile version of SO. Stupid ISP put my service cancellation request through right when I was done with my answer!

Answer (score 4):

You can also hook XMLHttpRequest send prototype. This will work for all sends (jQuery/dojo/etc) with one handler.

I wrote this code to handle a 500 page expired error, but it should work just as well to trap a 200 redirect. Ready the wikipedia entry on [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) onreadystatechange about the meaning of readyState.

```
// Hook XMLHttpRequest
var oldXMLHttpRequestSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
  //console.dir( this );

  this.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 500 && this.responseText.indexOf("Expired") != -1) {
      try {
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = this.responseText;
      } catch(error) {
        // IE makes document.documentElement read only
        document.body.innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    }
  };

  oldXMLHttpRequestSend.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got a working solulion using the answers from @John and @Arpad  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426947/4505142) and @RobWinch [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34366885/4505142)

I use Spring Security 3.2.9 and jQuery 1.10.2.

Extend Spring's class to cause 4XX response only from AJAX requests:

```
public class CustomLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    public CustomLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(final String loginFormUrl) {
        super(loginFormUrl);
    }

    // For AJAX requests for user that isn't logged in, need to return 403 status.
    // For normal requests, Spring does a (302) redirect to login.jsp which the browser handles normally.
    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request,
                         final HttpServletResponse response,
                         final AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if ("XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"))) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Access Denied");
        } else {
            super.commence(request, response, authException);
        }
    }
}
```

applicationContext-security.xml

```
  <security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="customAuthEntryPoint" >
    <security:form-login login-page='/login.jsp' default-target-url='/index.jsp'                             
                         authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true"
                         />    
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/errorPage.jsp"/> 
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp?logout" />
...
    <bean id="customAuthEntryPoint" class="com.myapp.utils.CustomLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg value="/login.jsp" />
    </bean>
...
<bean id="requestCache" class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache">
    <property name="requestMatcher">
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher">
        <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher">
            <constructor-arg>
              <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy"/>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg value="#{T(org.springframework.http.MediaType).APPLICATION_JSON}"/>
            <property name="useEquals" value="true"/>
          </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In my JSPs, add a global AJAX error handler as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17990019/4505142)

```
  $( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError ) {
      if ( jqxhr.status === 403 ) {
          window.location = "login.jsp";
      } else {
          if(thrownError != null) {
              alert(thrownError);
          } else {
              alert("error");
          }
      }
  });
```

Also, remove existing error handlers from AJAX calls in JSP pages:

```
        var str = $("#viewForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "get_mongoDB_doc_versions.do",
            type: "post",
            data: str,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) { ... },
//            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorStr) {
//                 if(textStatus != null)
//                     alert(textStatus);
//                 else if(errorStr != null)
//                     alert(errorStr);
//                 else
//                     alert("error");
//            }
        });
```

I hope it helps others.

**Update1**
I found that I needed to add the option (always-use-default-target="true") to the form-login config.
This was needed since after an AJAX request gets redirected to the login page (due to expired session), Spring remembers the previous AJAX request and auto redirects to it after login. This causes the returned JSON to be displayed on the browser page. Of course, not what I want.

**Update2**
Instead of using `always-use-default-target="true"`, use @RobWinch example of blocking AJAX requests from the requstCache. This allows normal links to be redirected to their original target after login, but AJAX go to the home page after login.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to ajax, there is a new [**Fetch API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) being developed, which allows manual redirect handling. [You need to check](https://caniuse.com/?search=fetch) if the current browser support is enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use statusCode option as in below case, redirects are usually 301, 302 status codes for redirects.

```
$.ajax({
    type: <HTTP_METHOD>,
    url:  {server.url},
    data: {someData: true},
    statusCode: {
        301: function(responseObject, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //yor code goes here
        },
        302: function(responseObject, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //yor code goes here
        }           
    }
})
.done(function(data){
    alert(data);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + textStatus);
})
.always(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
   alert('Ajax request was finished')
});
```

Comment: which version of jquery supports statusCode option?

Comment: its there since version 1.5, i guess, https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Okay, Anyway I was looking for server side redirect, for which the status code will be 200

Comment: on python flask server

Comment: @GuruVishnuVardhanReddy you should first go through the docs before exposing your ignorance publicly https://www.flaskapi.org/api-guide/status-codes/

Comment: I didn't say you solution was wrong, I said it didn't work for me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651467/302-redirection-error-before-200-success-code-in-flask

Answer (score 0):

Backend Spring `@ExceptionHandler`.

- 400 and error string for business related exception (to be shown on pop-up)
- 302 and Location header to error/login page for application exceptions for browser request (to be automatically redirected by the browser)
- 500/400 and Location header to error/login page for ajax requests to redirect by ajax callback

Exception details passed to error page via user session

```
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvise {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionHandlerAdvise.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        if (isBusinessException(ex)) {
            logger.warn(getRequestURL(request), ex);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(getUserFriendlyErrorMessage(ex), headers, BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            logger.error(getRequestURL(request), ex);
            userInfo.setLastError(ex);
            headers.add("Location", "/euc-portal/fault");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, headers, isAjaxRequest(request) ? INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR : FOUND);
        }
    }
}

private boolean isAjaxRequest(WebRequest request) {
    return request.getHeader("x-requested-with") != null;
}

private String getRequestURL(WebRequest request) {
    if (request instanceof ServletWebRequest) {
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = ((ServletWebRequest) request).getRequest();
        StringBuilder uri = new StringBuilder(servletRequest.getRequestURI());
        if (servletRequest.getQueryString() != null) {
            uri.append("?");
            uri.append(servletRequest.getQueryString());
        }
        return uri.toString();
    }
    return request.getContextPath();
}
```

LoginHandlerInterceptor

```
@Service
public class LoginHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (userInfo.getPrincipal() == null && !(request.getRequestURI().contains(LOGIN_URL) || request.getRequestURI().contains(FAULT_URL) || request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/app/css"))) {
            response.addHeader("Location", LOGIN_URL);
            response.setStatus(isAjaxRequest(request) ? BAD_REQUEST.value() : FOUND.value());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Client code

```
$.post('/app/request', params).done(function(response) {
    ...
}).fail(function(response) {
    if (response.getResponseHeader('Location')) {
        window.top.location.href = response.getResponseHeader('Location');
        return;
    }
    alert(response);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Additionally you will probably want to redirect user to the given in headers URL. So finally it will looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    //.... other definition
    complete:function(xmlHttp){
        if(xmlHttp.status.toString()[0]=='3'){
        top.location.href = xmlHttp.getResponseHeader('Location');
    }
});
```

UPD: Opps. Have the same task, but it not works. Doing this stuff. I'll show you solution when I'll find it.

Comment: This answer should be deleted by the author as he himself says that this doesn' work. He can post a working solution later. -1

Comment: The idea is good, but the problem is that "Location" header is never passed.

Comment: My edit was rejected, so... you have to use "var xmlHttp = $.ajax({ ...."  the variable can't be inside... then use: console.log(xmlHttp.getAllResponseHeaders());

Answer (score -3):

this worked for me:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

        console.log(xhr.status);
}
```

on success, ajax will get the same status code the browser gets from the server and execute it.

Comment: huh? this just logs to the console the status of the request? Which for success will be 2xx.